# TripleDes decryption with some invalid data at the beginning

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am trying to decrypt data using tripleDes. Everything looks fine but it has some invalid characters at the beginning? What am I doing wrong? For same data if call this function again and again these first few characters are always different but the rest of the data is same.

I am passing useHashing to false.

```
public static byte[] GetTripleDesDecryption(string dataToDecrypt, byte[] key, bool useHashing)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] plainbytes = null;
        byte[] cipherbytes;

        try
        {
            if (useHashing)
            {
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(key);
                hashmd5.Clear();
            }
            else
                keyArray = key;

            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tdes.Key = keyArray;
                tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                using (ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor())
                {
                    cipherbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dataToDecrypt);
                    plainbytes = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherbytes, 0, cipherbytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogMessage(e.Message + " Attribute Parsing error. DataToDecrypt = " + dataToDecrypt);
            throw e;
        }
        return plainbytes;
    }
```

This is what I get:

```
"�{c��]�sertion xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\"><saml:AttributeStatement><saml:Attribute Name=\"userID\"><saml:AttributeValue>456</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=\"financialInstitutionNumber\"><saml:AttributeValue>303986258</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=\"password\"><saml:AttributeValue>galaxy</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion>   "
```

Comment: You need the IV used during encryption.

Comment: Can you please exmplain it to me, I am not doing encryption it's coming from phoneApp. I am just parsing the encrypted request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the C# classes use a random IV if it is not set. Try to set the IV to a byte array of 8 bytes valued 00h bytes and try to decrypt with that. If that does not work, you will have to retrieve the IV somehow.

PS the right way is of course to request the blocksize from the tdes instance instead of putting in the literal 8

Comment: I did not understand the blocksize from tdes I used this.    byte[] iv = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
tdes.IV = iv;  This time first few characters were like this 4tghh9Crsertion xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:

Comment: I passed this for IV and it worked  byte[] iv = { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00 };   Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, it was a bit of a guess, although it was an educated one :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking back over your post and saw you are trying to decrypt a SAML assertion. SAML 2 is included in WIF, so I would consider downloading and using it. The abstraction is much easier to use than trying to reinvent the wheel.

As for the first answer I gave and comments from others: @Henk Holterman is focusing on the fact that an encryption mechanism uses botha  key (converted to bytes) and an Initialization Vector (IV). If an IV other than "standard" is used (ie, it was specified), you have to match it.

As this is SAML, focus on decrypting SAML so you can apply the assertion. You can do this with custom code, but your searching should focus on SAML.

Comment: This is what basically I am using not MD5     keyArray = key; 
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()) 
            { 
                tdes.Key = keyArray; 
                tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; 
                tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None; 
                using (ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor()) 
                { 
                   cipherbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dataToDecrypt); 
                    plainbytes = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherbytes, 0, cipherbytes.Length); 
                }

Comment: Edited. Good point, so i edited, but the SAML decryption is still the issue, and Microsoft has a good abstraction in WIF. If you can't use it, reflector on their code base might be an answer.There also might be an open source library on codeplex or similar.